# Picture File on RESULT_CANCELED

Tags: java, android, camera, google-glass

I want to be able to track image file names when a picture has been taken with the default Camera Glassware. This is so I can delete them when finished. I have the following code:

```
        ...
        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST);
 }

 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            String imgPath = data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH);
            mService.addToImageQueue(imgPath);
        }

        else if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            ...
        }
  }
```

If I tap, the resultCode returns `RESULT_OK`. When I dismiss (swipe down), I get the resultCode `RESULT_CANCELED`. This is how I intended it to work, except it still generates the image file even if the resultCode is `RESULT_CANCELED`... I honestly feel like this might be a bug since I tried to use `data.getStringExtra(Intents.EXTRA_PICTURE_FILE_PATH);` and got a `NullPointerException`. Am I doing something wrong? Is there a way to get this file name even on `RESULT_CANCELED`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a temporary file first (look at the `createImageFile()` method in [this tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html#TaskPath)). If successfully created, do two things:

1. Save the path of this file to a String.
2. Include this file's URI in the intent extra (`putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile))`).

If resultCode is `RESULT_CANCELED`, you can now trace back to the path of the temporary file and call `delete()` on it.

Here is some sample code:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Log.v("MainActivity", "Result successful.");
    } else if (requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PHOTO && resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
        Log.v(TAG, "Result canceled. Uri of file is " + mCurrentPhotoPath);
        File file = new File(mCurrentPhotoPath);
        if (file.exists()) {
            Log.v(TAG, "File exists.");
            if(file.delete()) {
                 Log.v(TAG, "File was successfully deleted!");
            } else {
                 Log.v(TAG, "File not successfully deleted.");
            }
        } else {
            Log.v(TAG, "File does not exist!");
        }


    }
}
```

Note: For `new File(mCurrentPhotoPath)` to work, remove "file:" from the beginning of `mCurrentPhotoPath`.

Comment: file is not exists but file continues to appear in the gallery :( How can I do that?